# How to re-write using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm wondering how I can re-write this using vectorization with numpy, assuming I change all lists to numpy arrays.

```
# dcdw1 = m x m array
# a1 = len(x) x m array
# a2 = len(x) x 1 array
# w2 = m x 1 array
# x = len(x) x m array
# y = len(x) x 1 array



for i in range(len(x)):
      for j in range(m):
            for k in range(m):
                dcdw1[k, j] = (a2[i] - y[i]) * a2[i] * (1 - a2[i]) * w2[j] * a1[i, j] * (1 - a1[i, j]) * x[i, k]
      # other stuff that uses dcdw1
```

Comment: What are `m`, `a1`, `a2`, `w2`, `y` ?

Comment: Just arrays with floats between 0 and 1. m is just a number

Comment: This makes no sense at every most-outer iteration you are overwriting contents of dcdw1. Also, write your matrix/vector sizes so people have an idea about what operation is being vectorized.

Comment: Yes, there are more things that happen in the outer loop, but I am interested in setting dcdw1 by vectorization @SıddıkAçıl

Comment: @MathiasStrohkirch I see your edit, but how about `y` ?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Updated now @Tiendung

Comment: Any ideas @SıddıkAçıl?

Comment: Currently working on it.

Comment: Take a look at my answer @MathiasStrohkirch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# dcdw1 = m x m array
# a1 = len(x) x m array
# a2 = len(x) x 1 array
# w2 = m x 1 array
# x = len(x) x m array
# y = len(x) x 1 array

import numpy as np
m = 10
lx = 4 # len(x)

dcdw1 = np.zeros([lx, m, m])
dcdw2 = np.zeros_like(dcdw1)
a1 = np.ones([lx, m]) * 0.5
a2 = np.ones([lx, 1]) * 2
w2 = np.ones([m, 1]) * 3
x = np.ones([lx, m]) * 4
y = np.ones([lx, 1]) * 5

for i in range(lx):
      for j in range(m):
            for k in range(m):
                dcdw1[i, k, j] = (a2[i] - y[i]) * a2[i] * (1 - a2[i]) * w2[j] * a1[i, j] * (1 - a1[i, j]) * x[i][k]
                # Why are you using j on rows and k on columns? anyways

print(dcdw1[-1])

first_term = np.reshape( (a2-y) * a2 * (1-a2), [lx, 1, 1] ) 
# this is on 3d tensor level applied to each matrix seperately
# corresponds to (a2[i] - y[i]) * a2[i] * (1 - a2[i])
print(first_term.shape) # [lx, 1, 1] obviously

a1_term = (a1 * (1-a1))[:, :, np.newaxis]
# On each matrix calculate this vector product [lx, m] and shape to [lx, m, 1]
print(a1_term.shape) 
row_level_term = a1_term * w2 # Element wise multiplication yet again
# w2 is [m, 1] so it is broadcasted to every matrix

row_level_tensor = first_term * row_level_term 
# this applies first term values to every matrix -> [lx, m, 1]
print(row_level_tensor.shape)

x = np.reshape(x, [lx, 1, 10])
# x is weird. Foreach matrix it is used as a coefficient for matrix rows
# x[i][k] # ignoring i, k is basically telling takes this row vector
# and dstack it m times with different coeffs
# to create giant linearly dependent matrices
print(x.shape)
dcdw2 = np.matmul(row_level_tensor, x) # mxm matrix product lx times
print(dcdw2[-1])
```

This is quite ugly but it gets the job done(two reshapes and a newaxis, ugh. People do not usually perform elementwise matrix ops on tensors I guess, at least I do not). I did not like overwriting `dcdw1`. This above creates a tensor where your current `dcdw1` is the last element. I checked it against your serial code with loops and the output is the same. You need to tweak your current code a bit, though.

Here is the [Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AloJtypxvwlmf6ELJkLZdhEUklRQh1dX) of the code.

Improvements and suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```py
dcdw1[k, j] = (a2[i] - y[i]) * a2[i] * (1 - a2[i]) * w2[j] * a1[i, j] * (1 - a1[i, j]) * x[i, k]
```

the long part `(a2[i] - y[i]) * a2[i] * (1 - a2[i]) * w2[j] * a1[i, j] * (1 - a1[i, j])`, I assign it as `temp`, will produce a `len(x) x m` array, while `x` is a `len(x) x m` array. So you can't obtain a `m x m` array here with just `*` operator.

Did you mean you want to add this result to `dcdw1[k, j]` for each `i` in `range(len(x))` as below ?

```py
dcdw1 = np.zeros([m,m])
for i in range(len(x)):
      for j in range(m):
            for k in range(m):
                dcdw1[k, j] += (a2[i] - y[i]) * a2[i] * (1 - a2[i]) * w2[j] * a1[i, j] * (1 - a1[i, j]) * x[i][k]
```

If so, here is the code you want:

```py
import numpy as np

# dcdw1 = m x m array
# a2 = len(x) x 1 array
# y = len(x) x 1 array
# w2 = m x 1 array
# a1 = len(x) x m array
# x = len(x) x m 

temp = (a2-y) * a2 * (1-a2) * w2.T * a1 * (1-a1)
dcdw1 = np.dot(temp.T, x).T
```

Why do I use `w2.T` ? Since `w2` is a column vector with shape of `m x 1`. It can't be broadcast to a `len(x) x m` array because their number of rows do not match. Instead I will transpose `w2` so that its number of columns matches `a1 * (1-a1)`s'. Similar to `temp`.